# Alignment in Impact block is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

As far as I see icons in the Impact block of the Profile page became black (old were gray) and currently alignment is broken:

- > [image: Shog9]
- > [image: JasonC]
- > [image: Journeyman Geek]

Comment: Not just black, they made it into  inline SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this looking? Some fixes went live recently.

Comment: Icons look gray (and aligned) again. Is black color gone forever?

Comment: @alexolut, I hope you don't want to return back to that ugly contrasting black color. Also, black bold icons masked thin text with the same color.